# Unable to correct dependencies

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, package-management

I have a 11.10 ubuntu server machine located on a VPS that has package problems.

I think this all started with my do-release-upgrade failed part way through. In any case, I can no longer use apt-get to install anything because of unmet dependencies.

```
root@vpsstart:/etc/apt# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Depends: libc-bin (= 2.13-20ubuntu5.3)
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.5) but 2.13-20ubuntu5.3 is installed
             Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.5)
 libmono-corlib4.0-cil : Depends: mono-runtime (>= 2.10.8.1) but 2.10.5-1ubuntu0.1 is installed
 libmono-i18n4.0-cil : Depends: mono-runtime (>= 2.10.8.1) but 2.10.5-1ubuntu0.1 is installed
 libnih-dbus1 : Depends: libnih1 (= 1.0.3-4ubuntu9.1) but 1.0.3-4ubuntu2 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

My sources.list looks like this:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric main restricted universe  
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-updates main restricted universe  
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric partner

deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib  
deb http://webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk/repository sarge contrib
```

I've tried apt-get clean and apt-get autoclean and of course I've done an apt-get update numerous times.

Any magic that will allow me to get my package system straightened out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: @Jobin the most important part here is... **he's using 11.10**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu as as server, I would **strongly recommend LTS** releases only. This question cannot be answered because [11.10 has been reached EOL already](http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life), and probably will be closed as off-topic.

Take the time to read on [how to upgrade EOL versions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades) at the Ubuntu Wiki page , but it would be preferable to do a fresh install.

[Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support) is the current stable LTS and it will supported until April 2017, but as a server in action I would suggest [Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.1/) (due to the [LTS new policies](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)). No matter if the page writes (12.04.2 LTS) scroll down and you will find the ubuntu-12.04.1-server image.

Comment: I agree with you.  I got into this mess by trying to upgrade to the 12.04 LTS using do-release-upgrade.  But when it failed part way through, I'm left with a system that can't be upgraded.  I'm hoping that I can upgrade rather than reinstall, because of the many hours of reconfiguration necessary if I need to merge in my /etc and stuff.   Any suggestions on my best strategy?

Comment: Did you read the wiki page I linked ? (EOL upgrades). I think you must change the sources.list file. I don't have a strategy as I haven't made such migration before.

Comment: Thanks for your time with this.   I have played around with putting both "precise" as well as back to "oneiric" in the sources.list.  But (after an update of course) I still have the same problem that won't allow me to install any packages.

Comment: Try to change the sources.list file as indicated in [Requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades#Requirements). Point into old.releases instead of current. Then do a system update and then try to upgrade the distribution.

Comment: You are right, I did miss old-releases being substituted for archives.  I tried that, but still am seeing the same problem.

Comment: I got my package system straight finally.   The final trick was to use old-releases with "precise" (rather than oneiric).  Then I got no more errors and I could then go back to "archive" with "precise" and update and upgrade things.   Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using quite an old and unsupported version of linux and their is no guarantee that the repositories are still maintained to be able to fix your current setup...  I'd would recommend a new installation of Ubuntu 13.10, especially if you are running a server machine...